# Issue with code behind ASPX

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASPX file with this button:

```
<asp:button id="cmdPartnerInfo" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
    Text="Partner Info" TabIndex="3">
</asp:button>
```

And in the ASPX.VB file I have this Sub:

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    cmdPartnerInfo.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return ShowPartnerContatcInfo();")
    imgStaff.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return AddStaffSelection();")
    lblDt.Text = ""

... snip ...

End Sub
```

However, there is a squiggly line under `cmdPartnerInfo` and the message is:

```
Error 38 'cmdPartnerInfo' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its 
protection level.
```

So it looks like the code in the vb file doesn't see the asp control in the aspx page.

Any help figuring out why this is happening is appreciated.

Thanks!
Eric

UPDATE:
These are the two directives at the top of the ASPX page.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Card" TagName="Banner" Src="~/banner.ascx" %>
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="projectpartlog.aspx.vb" Inherits="Project_and_Partners_Log" %>
```

Comment: Rename the button, save, rename back to `cmdPartnerInfo`. Note that you could/should use the button's [`OnClientClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx) property instead of `Attributes.Add("onclick"...`. You can avoid the postback by returning `false` in both ways.

Comment: have you renamed you aspx page?

Comment: I converted the project from VS2005 to VS2010. But the file name remained the same.

Comment: give it a try, change CodeFile="projectpartlog.aspx.vb" to CodeBehind="projectpartlog.aspx.vb"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="projectpartlog.aspx.vb" Inherits="Project_and_Partners_Log" %>
```

This directive means:

1. The **file name** for your "code behind" should be `projectpartlog.aspx.vb`
2. The **Class** name in the `projectpartlog.aspx.vb` file should be `Project_and_Partners_Log`

   ```
   Partial Class Project_and_Partners_Log
       Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

       Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

       End Sub

       Protected Sub cmdPartnerInfo_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdPartnerInfo_Click.Click     

         'Code.....

        End Sub

   End Class
   ```

Answer (score 3):

1. Check page's directive `<%@ Page` and ensure that you behind class
   belongs to you aspx file.
2. Next issue which you need to check is aspx.designer file(you should find your Button control declaration). Sometimes VS doesn't add declaration automatically, when you copy-paste a code.

Answer (score 2):

does your ASPX file has declaration of page directive having "CodeFile/Inherits" attribute? e.g. <@Page CodeFile="XYZ.aspx.vb" Inherits="XYZ" >

Answer (score 0):

I think you have converted your button to private add a new Button and remove it and then try.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your page directive.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Master/Mater.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeFile="Test.aspx.vb" Inherits="Test" %>
```

Check to see if the CodeFile property is set to the proper code file.

Comment: What is the name of your aspx.vb page? Make sure you are reading it from the actualy code behind file and not the page directive.